# Не могу понять, где ошибка

Tags: алгоритм, fortran

Matrix68. Дана матрица размера M × N и целое число K (1 ≤ K ≤ M). Перед строкой матрицы с номером K вставить строку из нулей.

```
 program ZZ

 integer, allocatable, dimension(:,:)::A, B

 integer::m, n, k, x, y
 print*,'Enter M'
 read*,m        
 print*,'Enter N'        
 read*,n
 print*,'Enter K'
 read*,k        
 allocate(a(m,n),b(m,n+1))
 do y=1,n+1
     read*,(a(x,y),x=1,m)
 end do        
 do y=1,n        
     b(k+1,y)=0        
 end do        
 if(1<=k.and.k<=m)then        
     do x=1,m
         do i=1,k        
             b(x,i)=a(x,i)        
         end do        
     end do        
     do 
         x=k+2,n+1        
         b(x,i)=a(x,i-1)
        end do
 else 
     do y=1,n
         print*,a(x,y)
     end do
 end if
 do 
     i=1,n+1
     print*,b(x,i)
 end do
 end program
```

Comment: @Чингиз Бостанов, Форматируйте свой код. Это способствует более полному пониманию задачи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немного не так. Если k находится во множестве [1,m], то все-таки циклы будут выглядеть так.

```
read*,m
print*,'Enter N'
read*,n
print*,'Enter K'
read*,k
if(1<=k.and.k<=m)then
  allocate(a(m,n),b(m+1,n))
  do y=1,n+1
     read*,(a(x,y),x=1,m)
  end do
  do y=1,n
      b(k,y)=0
  end do
  do x=1,k-1
     do y=1,n
       b(x,y)=a(x,y)
     end do
  end do
  do x=k,m
    do y=1,n
      b(x+1,y)=a(x,y)
    end do
  end do
end if

rem Дальше идет вывод на печать
```

У вас все время происходит путаница с индексами массивов. Тут надо быть немного аккуратней.

Comment: За исправление спасибо.
Но я чет не так сделал он не делает то что мне надо.(

Comment: Дана матрица размера M × N и целое число K (1 ≤ K ≤ M). Перед строкой матрицы с номером K вставить строку из нулей. --  Т.е. нужно скопривать из первой таблицы строки с первой по К-1, потом вставить строку из нулей и копировать остальные строки.
Что я понял не так?

Comment: Вообщем задачу сдал все переправил все работает.